# Flask doesn't get the right port

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

My computer rebooted and now my Flask server isn't working like it was.
Let me explain, I defined in `app.py` the following parameters :

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response, send_from_directory

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
STATIC_FOLDER = './static'

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.secret_key = 's_e_c_r_e_t'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return '''<h1>Flask</h1>
<p> Yay super Flask app </p>'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, threaded=True)
```

Then I do the usual `flask run`  in my Windows CMD and this appears :

```
D:\A_pb_api\api>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

and I can't reach it through my React like I could before the reboot `"http://localhost:5001/myroute"`

Can someone help me to get my Flask server run again and on port `5001` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was caused from the way I start Flask in my CMD.  I should do

```
python app.py
```

instead of

```
flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=5001
flask run
```

Comment: It looks like the port number is hardwired in the OP's code, so I wonder if an env var is not going to affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tip for you 
Create a file named `.flaskenv` and add this

```
FLASK_APP=app
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5001
```

Then start you app using `flask run`, it will automatically load these variable